# Can I add my custom file or edit existing file of the chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extensions, extension

I want to add my custom files like image, script, and etc to the extension. But after adding or saving extension file, the extension is crashed.

ex) This extension may have been corrupted

I want to solve this problem. Please help me.